# Integrating Monday.com Boards with SQL Database: Connection Troubleshooting

Tags: sql, database-connection, integration, monday.com

I'm trying to establish a connection between my Monday.com account and an SQL database. The goal is to sync data from Monday.com boards to the SQL database for further analysis. However, I'm facing some challenges during the setup process. Could someone provide guidance on how to successfully connect Monday.com boards to an SQL database?

Additional information:

I have already set up the SQL database and have the necessary credentials to access it.
I want to automate the process of transferring data from Monday.com boards to the SQL database on a regular basis.
The Monday.com API documentation seems to provide relevant information, but I'm unsure about the specific steps and best practices to establish the connection.
I'm familiar with SQL queries and basic programming concepts, so I'm comfortable working with code if necessary.